# API Blueprint: Best way to denote file upload?

Tags: rest, file-upload, markdown, apiblueprint

How would I denote a REST API using API Blueprint that is similar to the  [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads)

I'm expecting uploads of all different kinds of files so I see drive handles "multipart" uploads. I'd likely need to do something similar to that too.

How would this look in API Blueprint markdown?

I noticed that there isn't like a "file" primative, but there are headers? I'm pretty new to API Blueprint.

Comment: I believe this is duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207495/how-do-i-document-a-multipart-request-with-apiary please check it out and let me know.